# OSX Statusbar App using Swift

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I am trying to write a status bar app for OSX using swift. The equivalent code in Objective-C seems to work and shows up a status bar menu, but the following code does not:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusMenu: NSMenu

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var statusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
        var statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(NSVariableStatusItemLength))
        statusBarItem.menu = statusMenu
        statusBarItem.title = "TestApp"
    }

}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, what *does* it do?

Comment: @BergQuester the application runs and does nothing. If I disable LSUIElement, then a tray/dock icon appears.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `statusBarItem` var is going out of scope once the call to `awakeFromNib()` completes, you need to keep a reference to it. Try something like this:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusMenu: NSMenu
    var statusBarItem : NSStatusItem?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var statusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(NSVariableStatusItemLength))
        statusBarItem!.menu = statusMenu
        statusBarItem!.title = "TestApp"
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294196/os-x-10-10-yosemite-adding-a-menulet/24294589#24294589